# jquery animate not firing onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

i have a SELECT, and I want it to animate something onchange, heres the SELECT code:

```
<select id="account_select" onchange="submit_value()">
<option value="">Select account</option>
<option value="1">Account 1</option>
<option value="2">Account 2</option>
</select>
```

heres the jquery:

```
function show_keyboard ()
{
    $('.keyboard').animate({bottom: '0px'}, 2000);
}

function submit_value ()
{
    if (!is_number($('#account_select').val()))
    {
        alert('You must select an account');
    }
    else
    {
        show_keyboard();
    }
}
```

the problem is, that after i select an account, i have to click somewhere on the screen in order for the keyboard to appear via the show_keyboard function. i don't know why.

Comment: where do you trigger submit_value() ?

Comment: I think I would need to see the rest of your code, like the account_select container and the keyboard too.

Comment: @meo in the `onchange="submit_value()"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well i know that using jquery's change function is a better approach...this issue seemed to resolve itself after a browser refresh.

Answer (score 1):

It's better / cleaner to not use inline JavaScript.

Just use jQuery's `change()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/rw4qB/

**EDIT**

The code i would use:

```
function show_keyboard ()
{
    $('.keyboard').animate({bottom: '0px'}, 2000);
}

$('#account_select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        alert('Please select an account');
        return true;
    }

    show_keyboard();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="account_select">
```

jQuery

```
$('#account_select').change(submit_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryMIN.js"></script>
    <script>

    function hello() {
        var selObj = $('#direction');
        var slider = $('#slider');

        if (!parseInt(selObj.val()))
        {
             alert('You must select a direction');
        }
        else
        {
             switch(parseInt(selObj.val()))
             {
                case 1:
                    slider.animate({top: 100}, 800)
                break;

                case 2:
                    slider.animate({left: 100}, 800)
                break;

                case 3:
                    slider.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 }, 800)
                break;
             }
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>



<body>
    <select id="direction" onchange="hello()">
        <option value="">Select an direction</option>
        <option value='1'>down</option>
        <option value='2'>right</option>
        <option value='3'>reset</option>
    </select>
    <div id='slider' style='position: relative; display: block; background-color: #00f; width: 100px; height: 100px;'></div>
</body>
```

Replace the jquery reference with the path to your jquery-version.js file. If this does not work as expected, then something might be wrong with your jquery library file. Like mentioned above, I would not suggest using the inline method, but for the sake of example, i'm including it here.

Hope this helps.